# Css Transition auto, relation with other divs

Tags: css, width, transition

I'am currently trying to make a transition with css.

```
'.transition_line {
    display: inline-block;
    background:#FDBB58;
    width:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
}
:target .transition_line{
    width:53%;
}'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uv0frgyk/4/  Please see the JSfiddle.

If the h2 tag contains more or less text, I would like the transition automatically to fit container size. h2, transition_line, and the button must remain inline.

I'm open to any suggestions!

Thank you!

Comment: The container size like `:target .transition_line{ width:100%; }`?

Comment: I want to be able to add more text, or less,to h2, and the orange line to push the button to the right(perfectly align to the right of the container)without to put a fix size to the orange line.Now if I put :target .transition_line{ width:100%; } it push my buttons on the second line.